# Problem in Installing Golang ZMQ for windows - fatal error: czmq.h: No such file or directory

Tags: go

I tried to use `ZMQ` library in Golang and use instructions from the following page: https://zeromq.org/languages/go/. Based on the document, `libsodium`, `libzmq` and `czmq` are dependencies.

GCC downloaded from https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/download/ and installed in `C:\gcc`.

Then for installing `vcpkg` (used for installing other packages) the https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg repository is downloaded and extracted at `C:\dev` directory. The following command is  used for installation:

```
C:\dev>bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
```

To install `libsodium` based on https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation, the following commands executed:

```
cd C:\dev
vcpkg integrate install
vcpkg install libsodium
```

To install `libzmq` and `czmq` following commands are used:

```
vcpkg install zeromq:x64-windows-static
vcpkg install czmq:x64-windows-static
```

After installing dependencies I tried to install `zeromq` for Golang. But running the following command:

```
go get gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq.v4
```

Caused this error:

```
go get gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq.v4
# gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq.v4
C:\Users\Noori\go\pkg\mod\gopkg.in\zeromq\goczmq.v4@v4.1.0\auth.go:4:10: fatal error: czmq.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "czmq.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Windows and Golang version: Windows 10-x64 and Go 1.17.3

```
go version
go version go1.17.3 windows/amd64
```

I'm a beginner in golang, please help me in this field.

Comment: Did you install libzmq or CZMQ like it says on the install page?

Comment: I tried `libzmq`

Comment: The install page says `gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq` is a go binding for `CZMQ`, so you also need to install that (it also says you need to install `libsodium`)

Comment: @JimB I installed `libsodium`, `libzmq` and `czmq` library. That was the hard way. After that I found this file: `C:\MinGW\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\czmq.h`. Even now when I run `go get gopkg.in/zeromq/goczmq.v4`, the previous error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, I discovered how to install `zmq` for `Go`.

First of all, I tried another `GCC` software. Software downloaded from https://www.msys2.org/ and installed on `C:\msys64`.

Then add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable of the windows.

Then run the following commands one by one (**before executing the commands please see the update 5 Nov 2022 at the bottom of this solution**).

```
pacman -Su
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
pacman -S base-devel gcc vim cmake
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libsodium
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zeromq
```

Finally, run the `Go` install command:

```
go get github.com/pebbe/zmq4
```

Finished.
Now it seems easy :)

---

****Update 5 Nov 2022****

By updating MSYS some errors were raised in this solution:

> David Macek david.macek.0@gmail.com is unknown trust

Based on [this page](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2343#issuecomment-780121556), before running the pacman command, its configurations should edit.

To work correctly, edit the `C:\msys64\etc\pacman.conf` file and edit the line `SigLevel` to `SigLevel = Never`.

Comment: I tried your method, without adding the paths to env `set CGO_CFLAGS=-IC:\msys64\mingw64\include` and  `set CGO_LDFLAGS=-LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib`. I get `zmq.h not found`. But when I do add them, I get a tone of error  `ld.exe: $WORK\b043\_x008.o:wrappers_windows.cgo2.c:(.text+0x468): undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_msg_recv'` Do you have any other indication on how you did it?

Comment: Do you download the last version of GCC from https://www.msys2.org? because I tried another GCC and they don't work properly.

Comment: I finally figured it out. It was because the env car for the libzmq.dll was not set. And the cgo ldflags did not include the name of the lib file as well. I've sent a PR to the git of pebble to hopefully include these precisions